# HTML Preview via JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, preview

I'd like to throw together a quick HTML preview window that takes the contents of a text area and shows it in a modal dialogue with a single close button. The contents should be rendered as HTML.

Not sure how to go about this.. what's the best way?

Comment: Which part is tripping you up?

Comment: You can go for any of these modal boxes: http://kirank.blog.com/2009/10/31/jquery-model-box/ [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is another getting very popular.

Comment: @Matchu: I assume no part yet... He is *probably* looking for pre-made model box solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI, something like this:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false });

function preview() {
  $('#dialog').html($('#mytext').val());
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Anywhere you want. Just add a link or button somewhere and call `preview` when it's clicked, for example: `<button onclick="preview();">Preview</button>`